# WhatsAPP Business API - Connection refused. Please check if wacore is running: wacore:6251 error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, whatsapp

I've installed WhatsApp business client on my linux docker containers, I have managed to hit the `/v1/health` route perfectly and have also changed the default password through an endpoint.

But, I'm getting an error when I try to access POST request `/v1/contacts` . The error is:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "version": "v2.41.2",
        "api_status": "stable"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 1014,
            "title": "Internal error",
            "details": "Connection refused. Please check if wacore is running: wacore:6251"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, my wacore container is indeed running:

[Docker Container Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mSNZ.png)

P.S: Some questions already posted here with similar titles don't solve my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] the question to elaborate on which similar questions you've found and why those solutions didn't work for you? That'll help us to find a solution for you

Comment: @Adriaan basically, some similar questions don't even have a single answer. One question had an answer to set the environment variable, which I have already set. One said to just restart the container, I tried that too.